# Correctly save data in csv file from php

Tags: php, csv

I have data like this `$fields = array('0001','0002','0003','00004');`

I need put this data into csv file, I use:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
```

But when open `file.csv` in excel, starting nulls (0) are removed and I see data like this

```
 1|2|3|4
```

How to store starting nulls in csv file?

Comment: I bet the leading zeros _are_ in the CSV file (you didn’t check, did you?) – but Excel discards them when opening the file.

Comment: open it in a text editor, Excel will `interpret` the CSV. nulls are ususally empty e.g. 0001,,0002

Comment: Ditto what @CBroe said but minus the unnecessary sarcasm.

Comment: Sorry you meant triming numbers. I assume the CSV is currently 0001,0002 but you want '0001','0002' to identify them as strings

Comment: This is the fault of Excel. If your file is to be used *only* with Excel (you won't be able to use it anywhere else if you do this) there is a horrible, horrible work-around, but you can't use `fputcsv()`, you will have to do it manually. If you make your files contain `="0001",="0002",="0003"` etc, Excel will display it correctly. But the data then becomes useless pretty much everywhere else, so I don't recommend this approach.

Comment: Besides that, you musst define the delimiter and the string enclosure. See: http://php.net/manual/function.fputcsv.php